# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager вью во всю ширину

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Задача такая нужно вместить вью в ширину на весь экран в GridLayoutManager(this , 2). Сделал набросок для визуального понятие[image: изображения]. Как решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы так сделать необходимо в `GridLayoutManager` установить кастомный `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup` через метод `setSpanSizeLookup`. Вот хороший пример с кодом [тут](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html).